# Can I use a timestamp variable in a where statement in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, timestamp

I would like to select a certain batch of data from a large database. As each batch is assigned an "upload_time", it should be possible to select only this batch using a simple where statement. However, I cannot seem to make this work: the procedure simply appends all data to TABLE_B rather than just one batch. Below is the code I have tried so far:

```
time_now timestamp;

begin

    time_now := current_timestamp;

    insert into TABLE_A (column_1, column_2, ... , UPLOAD_TIME)
    select column_A, column_B, ... , time_now
    from TABLE_B
    where UPLOAD_TIME = time_now;

end;
/
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you see if you `SELECT UPLOAD_TIME FROM TABLE_B`?

Comment: I'm surprised that it would return anything at all. `current_timestamp` returns the current date and time in the session time zone, with fractional second precision. The chance of anything in TABLE_B precisely matching the exact timestamp of the start of your block seems to me pretty low.

Comment: Sorry I should have added in the question - as data is appended (during the same procedure) it is assigned a timestamp. Each batch can be identified by a unique timestamp in TABLE_B. But in the same procedure, is it not possible to select only the data which has just been appended to TABLE_B, to TABLE_A, by writing a where statement? Sorry if this was not clear beforehand.

Comment: mathguy - I can see all the UPLOAD_TIMES in table b - I know that they exist. I think I am using the current_timestamp function incorrectly.

Comment: That should work just fine. My suspicion is that your time_now value is not being updated for each batch.

My suggestion is to define a  batch column and manage it, rather than use the timestamp as a stand in. Down the road it will be much easier to specify a batch id of 20376 than a specific timestamp value.

Comment: Note Current_timestamp returns current time by nano-second resolution. Does this match timestamp values in your table?

Comment: Might this be a simple column_name vs variable name mixup ? Best practice is to prefix variable names (eg v_time_now) so they don't get confused with column names. If you have a PL/SQL variable time_now and use the identifier time_now in a SQL statement referring to a table with a column named time_now, the identifier will be interpreted as referring to the column not the PL/SQL variable.

Comment: Brian Leach - Thank you for your suggestion - I am now using a unique Batch ID and my problem has been resolved.